Help identifying partially built set
Need help identifying this partially built set so I can find directions to finish.  I have looked and looked, but can't figure out what set this might be - thank you all for your help.


Using the Bricklink "Appearance in Inv" tool and looking for sets that had those 4 1x4 slopes, 8 1x2 grill slopes and 2 1x4 bricks with a groove, I found out it's set 9500 - Sith Fury-class Interceptor:


https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9500-1#T=S&O={%22iconly%22:0}

Thank you so much for your help - by any cnace is there a way to get a repop of the  half dome windshield?  I do not have that piece.

What's a "repop"? Perhaps you mean "spare"?

yes - a spare - I assume I need to watch ebay is it the same for any other kits or is it a one of a kind?

@user27821 you can buy individual parts on bricklink.  The part in question is listed here:  https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50747pb07&idColor=13#T=S&C=13&O=%7B%22color%22:13,%22iconly%22:0%7D   For relatively inexpensive printed parts it's probably worth paying a bit more for a new part to lower the risk of scratches/etc.  In this case you'll primarily be paying for shipping either way.

Thank you for your help.
